# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt - spring security version is 5.3.2

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt, bcrypt

I have a problem with authenticating my user once I post my API I got this error,
my database is restored from a PHP based source code and hashed passwords start with :

```
$2y$
```

I don't want to update my database, is there any way to get through this error?

> further information: my spring version is 5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and my
>   spring security version is 5.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Loyalty</groupId>
    <artifactId>OpenLoyalty</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OpenLoyalty</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.2.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>5.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-security.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>

            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the `BCrypt` version to use with `Spring Security`'s `BCryptPasswordEncoder` with the `BCryptVersion` enum. This was an added feature in version **5.2.0**. By default the version is set to `$2A`. Hence why you are unable to authenticate in your app.

Your security configuration would look something like:

```java
...
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.BCryptVersion;

@Configuration
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y); // specified your bcrypt version here
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I can't import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.BCryptVersion; I have added my pom file in Question.

Comment: I see from your pom you are trying to use `BUILD-SNAPSHOT` w/o a Spring Snapshots `<repository>` in your pom. So instead of your snapshot overrides, your Spring Security version is actually what is used in the Spring Boot 2.1.x which is 5.1.x see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L181). More importantly, Spring Boot 2.1.x is not intended to be used with those overridden versions and may encounter issues. I recommend upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2 to use Spring Security 5.2 which has the `BCryptVersion` enum.